# drush "Call to undefined function module_exists()"

Tags: drush

I cannot execute drush in my environment.
Drush is installed using

```
php -r "readfile('https://s3.amazonaws.com/files.drush.org/drush.phar');" > /usr/local/bin/drush \
&& chmod +x /usr/local/bin/drush \
&& drush --yes init
```

status seems ok:

```
root@c0ec24eaf070:/var/www/html# drush status
 Drupal version         :  7.43                                    
 Site URI               :  http://localhost                        
 Database driver        :  mysql                                   
 Database hostname      :  172.20.0.3                              
 Database port          :  3306                                    
 Database username      :  root                                    
 Database name          :  drupal                                  
 PHP configuration      :  /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini              
 PHP OS                 :  Linux                                   
 Drush script           :  /usr/local/bin/drush                    
 Drush version          :  8.1.3                                   
 Drush temp directory   :  /tmp                                    
 Drush configuration    :  /var/www/html/sites/default/drushrc.php 
 Drush alias files      :                                          
 Drupal root            :  /var/www/html                           
 Drupal Settings File   :  sites/default/settings.php              
 Site path              :  sites/default
```

but any command (such as watchdog-delete) fail with:

```
root@c0ec24eaf070:/var/www/html# drush watchdog-delete all

Fatal error: Call to undefined function module_exists() in     phar:///usr/local/bin/drush/commands/core/drupal/environment_7.inc on line 187
Drush command terminated abnormally due to an unrecoverable error.                                                                                                   [error]
Error: Call to undefined function module_exists() in phar:///usr/local/bin/drush/commands/core/drupal/environment_7.inc, line 187
```

FYI The environment is a drupal:7.43 [docker container](https://hub.docker.com/_/drupal/) and goes ever worse if I upgrade to 7.50

```
root@80116582cabe:/var/www/html# drush status
 Drupal version         :  7.50                                    
 Site URI               :  http://localhost                        
 Database driver        :  mysql                                   
 Database hostname      :  172.20.0.3                              
 Database port          :  3306                                    
 Database username      :  root                                    
 Database name          :  drupal                                  
 PHP configuration      :  /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini              
 PHP OS                 :  Linux                                   
 Drush script           :  /usr/local/bin/drush                    
 Drush version          :  8.1.3                                   
 Drush temp directory   :  /tmp                                    
 Drush configuration    :  /var/www/html/sites/default/drushrc.php 
 Drush alias files      :                                          
 Drupal root            :  /var/www/html                           
 Drupal Settings File   :  sites/default/settings.php              
 Site path              :  sites/default                           

root@80116582cabe:/var/www/html# drush watchdog-delete all

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function cache_get() in /var/www/html/includes/module.inc:754
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/includes/module.inc(954): module_implements('system_theme_in...')
#1 /var/www/html/modules/system/system.module(2511): module_invoke_all('system_theme_in...')
#2 /var/www/html/includes/theme.inc(798): _system_rebuild_theme_data()
#3 /var/www/html/includes/theme.maintenance.inc(57): list_themes()
#4 /var/www/html/includes/bootstrap.inc(2857): _drupal_maintenance_theme()
#5 /var/www/html/includes/errors.inc(179): drupal_maintenance_theme()
#6 /var/www/html/includes/bootstrap.inc(2594): _drupal_log_error(Array, true)
#7 [internal function]: _drupal_exception_handler(Object(Error))
#8 {main}
  thrown in /var/www/html/includes/module.inc on line 754
Drush command terminated abnormally due to an unrecoverable error.                                                                                                   [error]
Error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function cache_get() in /var/www/html/includes/module.inc:754
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/includes/module.inc(954): module_implements('system_theme_in...')
#1 /var/www/html/modules/system/system.module(2511): module_invoke_all('system_theme_in...')
#2 /var/www/html/includes/theme.inc(798): _system_rebuild_theme_data()
#3 /var/www/html/includes/theme.maintenance.inc(57): list_themes()
#4 /var/www/html/includes/bootstrap.inc(2857): _drupal_maintenance_theme()
#5 /var/www/html/includes/errors.inc(179): drupal_maintenance_theme()
#6 /var/www/html/includes/bootstrap.inc(2594): _drupal_log_error(Array, true)
#7 [internal function]: _drupal_exception_handler(Object(Error))
#8 {main}
  thrown in /var/www/html/includes/module.inc, line 754
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It resolved to be simply the missing mysql-client package :-(

So:

```
apt-get install -y mysql-client
```

resolves the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to provide an alternate answer in case other people are experiencing this issue but already have MySQL installed. When I tried executing Drush commands, I was getting

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function module_exists() in /usr/local/src/drush/commands/core/drupal/environment_7.inc on line 187

I am running Drupal 7 on a Debian server and my issue was fixed by restarting MySQL and then restarting Apache:

`/usr/sbin/service mysql start`

`service apache2 restart`

Edit: in once case, I was receiving this error because the database user password had somehow been changed and did not match the credentials in Drupal's settings.php file. In that case, I restored the password in MySQL to match what was in the settings.php file. Using command line and logged into MySQL (MySQL version 5.5.3):

```
SET PASSWORD FOR 'user'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('password');
```

Answer (score 0):

For Windows users, add the Path to Environment Variables where mysql.exe sits.